# Error in my HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

The following HTML code has an error as the tabs are not changing when I click on Students' statistics for example.

I think the problem is not in the inside nav-tabs but in the head, but I do not know where...

Could you suggest of a website to check the errors as well? I have tried several ones but they give me strange errors like: that the coding is not defined...

```js
function show(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
  return false;
}

function hide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.borderradius {
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.content {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.my_text {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: italic;
  font-color: #303030
}

.left {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #07B;
}

.body {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-tabs.centered>li,
.nav-pills.centered>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  /* ie7 fix */
  zoom: 1;
  /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}

.nav-tabs.centered,
.nav-pills.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

.c3-chart-arcs-title {
  fill: black;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 6px 1px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Full height image header */

.bgimg-1 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("Images/views.jpg");
  min-height: 120%;
}

.button4 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.button4 {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.button4:focus {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="container" id="header">
  <!-- Put the background picture here -->
  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <h1 class="w3-wide w3-center">ANALYSIS OF HIGH SCHOOLS' PERFORMANCE IN THE INITIAL PHASE OF THE GETI </h1>
  <div style="line-height:77%;"> <br> <br> </div>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs centered">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#project" data-toggle="tab">About the project     </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#students" data-toggle="tab">Students' statistics     </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#hschool" data-toggle="tab">High schools' statistics     </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#me" data-toggle="tab">Who am I     </a> </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <!-- Tab1: Project -->
    <div id="project" class="tab-pane fade in active w3-container w3-content w3-padding-32" style="max-width:1050px">
      <h3 class="w3-wide w3-center">ABOUT THE PROJECT </h3>
      <br>
      <p class="w3-container" style="margin: 0 05%">This webapp has been developed as part of my Bachelor's thesis to analyze the performance of the students in the initial phase of the GETI Degree (Industrial Technologies Engineering) and how their prior high school affects their results. </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab2: Students -->

    <div id="students" class="tab-pane fade w3-container w3-content w3-padding-16" style="max-width:1050px">
      <br>
      <CENTER> <button class="button button4" type="button" onclick="show('One');hide('Group');hide('Average');">Specific subject     </button>
        <button class="button button4" type="button" onclick="hide('One');show('Group');hide('Average');">Group of subjects     </button>
        <button class="button button4" type="button" onclick="hide('One');hide('Group');show('Average');">Average grade     </button>
        <CENTER>
          <div id="One" style="display: block;" class="w3-wide w3-center">Statistics about a specific subject </div>
        </CENTER>
        <CENTER>
          <div id="Group" style="display: none;" class="w3-wide w3-center">Statistics about a group of subjects </div>
        </CENTER>
        <CENTER>
          <div id="Average" style="display: none;" class="w3-wide w3-center">Average grade </div>
        </CENTER>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab3: Hschool -->
    <div id="hschool" class="tab-pane fade w3-container w3-content w3-padding-32" style="max-width:1050px">
      <h3 class="w3-wide w3-center">HIGH SCHOOLS' STATISTICS </h3>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab4: Me -->
    <div id="me" class="tab-pane fade w3-container w3-content w3-padding-32" style="max-width:1050px">
      <h3 class="w3-wide w3-center">WHO AM I? </h3>
      <p class="w3-container" style="margin: 0 05%">I am an Industrial Technologies Engineering Student from ETSEIB University. I have developed this web-app as part of my Bachelor Thesis in Data Mining. </p>
      <h3 class="w3-center">Contact information </h3>

      <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">

        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="w3-center w3-grey w3-padding-32">
    <p> &copy <a href="https://etseib.upc.edu/ca" target="_blank"> ETSEIB      
     </a> reserves the rights of all the displayed data | M </p>
    <div class="w3-left-align w3-margin-left w3-small">
      <p>
        <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Escola Tècnica Superior d'Enginyeria Industrial de Barcelona <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Universitat Politècnica de Catalunya <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Avda. Diagonal 647, 08028 Barcelona <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone: +34 93 401
        66 15
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Please update it with relevant links to external content. w3schools css file is not something I would personally link to in a page I wrote. There is no code that wires up "Students' Statistics" to anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add this code before the closing tag of body tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! @Bagzie, can I add it in the head part? Or should I add it as well in the body?

Comment: you should add it in the body part, but near the </body>

Comment: and also in the head? Or should I remove it from the head and have it ONLY near the </body>?

Comment: the head part should only have tha css link for bootstrap that u added earlier

Answer (score 1):

Run your code in this validator:
https://validator.w3.org/

Choose "validate by direct input" if you wish to just paste in your code.
Correct whatever error you can. Update the snippet with what errors might be left.